# Declare variable in python

Tags: python, variables, variable-declaration

I want to use a function to put values in a variable. But one of the parameters of this function is the parameter I want to expand. It looks like this:

```
X_train, y_train = load_images_to_data('a', 'data/a', X_train, y_train)
```

But do I have to declare the variable before this part of my program? For example typing something like

```
X_train
y_train
```

or

```
X_train = ( , , , )
y_train = ( , , , )
```

My code idea comes from [here](https://blog.tanka.la/2018/10/28/build-the-mnist-model-with-your-own-handwritten-digits-using-tensorflow-keras-and-python/). And I wanted to change the code so I would still use de MNIST data for training but my own data for testing. But then my X_test and y_test should have an initial value.

Comment: Does it give you an error when you run it? Ifso then maybe you want to try something like global X_train

Comment: In general, you don't need to *declare* a variable in Python, but if you want to pass it to a function as an argument, you must *initialize* it with something.

Comment: This line of code looks like you're _reassigning_ the variables as the output from the function, so you need to have the data assigned to the variables to pass in to the function in the first place

Comment: Python doesn't have declarations, period. A variable is created the first time you assign a value to its name.

Comment: @PNX using a global variable is rarely the best solution to a problem; see [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: The line you show in the question takes *existing* values `X_train` and `y_train`, pass them to the function, the *reassigns* the values returned by `load_images_to_data` to those same names. The variables have to be *defined* before you can make that function call.

Comment: @G.Anderson yeah I only use global variables when I have trouble with variables and functions. Depending on the rest of Joes De Jonge's code it may be (even though I agree it's generally a bad idea) a decent idea to use global. 

Comment: Googling the code gives [this](https://blog.tanka.la/2018/10/28/build-the-mnist-model-with-your-own-handwritten-digits-using-tensorflow-keras-and-python/) tutorial. It seems that Joes de Jonge's code should initialize these variables as numpy arrays.